# Correct way to load bulk data

Tags: python, libmemcached, memcachedb

I am trying to load a huge amount of data into memcachedb.
I am running some queries on MySQL database, and I want to store the results of these queries in memcachedb for later easy access.

Currently, I was just using simple set commands to store the results in memcachedb but since there are billions of these results, storing them one by one in a loop is very inefficient and time-consuming. So, I was wondering if there is a better way to load data into memcachedb? Like a data import wizard in traditional RDMS

I am using pylibmc to connect to memcachedb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pylibmc library has the [`set_multi`](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html#pylibmc.Client.set_multi) function, which sends a bunch of commands in one go:

```
mc.set_multi({
    'key': 'Hello',
    'another': True,
    #[..]
})
```

This should probably work well enough. If you have *billions* of keys, you probably want to split it into chunks of a few thousand.

You can probably squeeze a bit more performance if you just send the commands over a socket. the [memcache protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt)
is pretty simple. This has the advantage that you can add the `noreply` flag, so the server won't bother sending a reply. Of course, this means you can't do any error checking and that losing a few keys for whatever reason is fine.

Here's a simple proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

data = 'set key_1 0 86400 5\r\nabcde\r\n'
data += 'set key_2 0 86400 5\r\nzxcvb\r\n'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 11211))
s.sendall(data)
print(s.recv(8192))
s.close()

# Verify if it worked!
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 11211))
s.sendall('get key_1\r\n')
s.sendall('get key_2\r\n')
print(s.recv(8192))
s.close()
```

Which should output:

```
STORED
STORED

VALUE key_1 0 5
abcde
END
VALUE key_2 0 5
zxcvb
END
```

The format of the `set` command is:

```
set <key> <flags> <exptime> <data_size> [noreply]\r\n
<data>\r\n
```

Of course, this is just a proof-of-concept; a slightly more advanced example might be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

def make_set(n, data):
    return 'set key_{} 0 86400 {}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(n, len(data), data)

data = open('/etc/aliases').readlines()
commands = [ make_set(n, d.strip()) for n, d in enumerate(data) if d.strip() != '' ]

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 11211))
s.sendall(''.join(commands))
print(s.recv(65000))

# Verify if it worked!
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 11211))
for n in range(0, len(commands)):
    s.sendall('get key_{}\r\n'.format(n))
print(s.recv(65000))
s.close()
```

If you're getting data from MySQL, then consider making a `set` command with an SQL query! For example:

```
select
    concat('set key_', page_id, ' 0 86400 ', length(page_title), '\r\n', page_title, '\r\n')
    as cmd
from page limit 2;
```

Not sure this is actually faster, but I suspect it is.

Comment: Yes I found the multi_set function, that works better than individual set, but I was looking for more like a batch import functionality available for memcachedb (database). I am using multi_set for now.

Comment: @Wajahat I'm not sure what you mean with "batch import functionality"? If you're looking for a `import_my_four_billion_keys_from_mysql_efficiently()`-function, then that doesn't really exist AFAIK, but you can build one yourself quite easily as outlined...